# How to manage universal app and their images for iPhone, iPod and iPad

Tags: ios, xib

I am going to develop a new app. For every Screen (UIViewController) I will use separate xib.

So, also there will be different images for every screen.

For now, I want to use my app on following devices.

1. iPhone 3
2. iPhone 3GS
3. iPhone 4
4. iPhone 4S
5. iPhone 5
6. iPad
7. iPad2
8. iPad Mini
9. iPod (3rd, 4th, 5th generations)

So, For these iOS Devices, How can I manage xib and their respective images.

For simply my question, I would say that, How many image I required to "CLICK BUTTON IMAGE" on different devices, and how can I give names to them, as I read @2x, 2x@ etc

So, I would be thankful to one, who specifically write answer to my query and get me rid of this confusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These lines are straight from [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17)

```
MyImage.png - Default version of an image resource.
MyImage@2x.png - High-resolution version of an image resource for devices with Retina displays.
MyImage~iphone.png - Version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch.
MyImage@2x~iphone.png - High-resolution version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch devices with Retina displays.
```

Basically there are only 5 sizes

1. iPhone/iPod Touch 320x480
2. iPhone/iPod Touch having retina display 640x960
3. iPhone/iPod touch 5th 640x1136
4. iPad with non retina display 768x1024
5. iPad With retina display 1536x2048
6. iPad mini 768x1024

For list 1 your `MyImage~iphone.png` will work
For list 2 and 3 your `MyImage@2x~iphone.png` will work
For list 4 and 6 your `MyImage.png` will work
For list 5 your `MyImage.png` will work.

so you need only four image.

Comment: you did not read the Question carefully, the xib types are also mentioned in that. Please refer some data on it too. Thanks